# How to structure my classes correctly

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

I am runing into some difficulties in the interaction between my classes in my multithreaded application, my main chat server class first creates a DBConnection manager class and then creates a thread for each client connecting to my server. When the client connects I pass the connection to the client thread so that the client may interact with the DB and then return the connection to the pool when it is finished.

The problem occurs that if the connection to the DB drops there is no way for my client thread to re-establish the database connection pool as the only way it can re-initialise is talking to its 'super', now I cannot use the super statement as my clientThread extents Thread and not my main chatserver class. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Delegation usually is a better design choice than inheritance.  Foo *has* a Bar often gives you more options than Foo *is* a Bar.

> my clientThread extents Thread

Don't do that.  Your clientThread object should just be a plain Thread that is constructed with some ClientFoobar object that implements Runnable.

```
class Client implements Runnable {
    private final DBConnectionManager dbConnectionManager;
    private ...other state...

    public Client(DBConnectionManager dbConnectionManager,...) {
        this.dbConnectionManager = dbConnectionManager;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { ...interact with remote client... }
}

Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Client(dbConnectionManager,...)).start();
```

Comment: hi james, perhaps I didnt explain well, my main class creates the db connection and I pass that into each thread so that I dont create a connection for each thread, the thread just makes a connection (pulling from the connection pool) when data exchange is needed. Basically I need to get my clientthread to talk to the main class which is where the dbconnection would need to be re-established if it is dropped.

Comment: @XarionComoretto, It would be cleaner to make the code that establishes the connection be part of the Client class, and have the server thread pass all of the objects that the Client will need as arguments when it constructs the client.  That's what I was trying to illustrate with my example.

Comment: thanks, it is going to be an issue for me to keep a connection open for each client that connects as your solution suggests but if i dont come right I'll just have to move the dbconnection manager into the client thread.

Answer (score 0):

figured out how I can do it using some of your insight @james

I changed:

```
    public class clientThread extends Thread {
    }
```

To:

```
    public class clientThread extends MultiThreadChatServer implements Runnable {
    }
```

this allowed me to use my super class to reinitialise my connection pool when it drops the db connection.

In my Main class MultithreadChatServer I created a function to re-init the db connection (which is also called on the application start up) Now each of my threads will use a connection from the pool when they require (just need to make the pool big enough of course)